# Buttons won't work on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been working with Tkinter for a week or two now and I've had no problems using buttons. But with this project, my script works fine until I add a button, then it won't run anymore. Can someone help me fiture this out. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
from sys import argv
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter
import random

script, infile = argv

class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("ImagePro")
        Button(self.root, text ="ASdf").pack()


        #Original
        original = Image.open(infile)
        (w, h) = (original.size[0], original.size[1])
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(original)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi)
        label.grid(row =0, column=0, padx=5,pady=5)

        img = original.copy()
        pixels = img.load()
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                pixels[x,y]= 22
        tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label = Label(self.root, image=tkpi2)
        label.grid(row =0, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)



        self.root.mainloop()


MyApp()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `pack` and `grid` layouts.

"Don’t mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with." - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Pick one for the master window and stick with it. If you need to use multiple layouts, use a different `frame` for each one.

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm going to stick with grid